# How to establish a Apache2 proxy for a localhost:3000 node.js based application

Tags: proxy, localhost, apache2, bitnami, vapid

I'm trying to figure out how to link my Apache2 server running on AWS Lightsail to an application I'm housing that uses http://localhost:3000 when activated—it's a simple Node.js based CMS called Vapid. I have the server linked to my domain name—bigsheepcollective.com—and I can get Vapid running through the AWS terminal, but it's only the Apache2 landing page that shows up on my domain name. I saw a tutorial [here](https://mallinson.ca/posts/12/vapid-on-digital-ocean) that goes over establishing a proxy pass on an Nginx ran server but I'm not sure how to do the same thing for one using Apache2.

I've tried using the Nginx tutorial and I've also don't some extensive searches into proxy setups for Apache2, but I'm confused about what type of proxy I need when it comes to running an application that uses http//:localhost:3000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Bitnami Engineer here.

You can include these lines in the /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf file or in the specific .conf file you created for your application

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
```

This way you will access your application when accessing the public IP of your instance or its associated domain.

This guide in our documentation explains the whole process to configure a Node.js application on top of Bitnami.

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/mean/administration/create-custom-application-nodejs/

Comment: That worked! Thanks Bitnami Man!! 

Added this, then started Vapid via pm2 start pm2.json.